# Unity3D game on raspberry pi 3 b+

Tags: unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi

I want to make a simple 2D game in Unity3D and run it on my raspberry pi 3 b+. I read some topics where they achieved this using android emulator on rbPi but all info is outdated (2016). I'm wondering what are my options at this point? Can I run my unity project on Raspbian? Do I have to use emulators? Can I run it on Windows 10 IoT?

I'd like to use it on Raspbian if there is any chance.

The performance should not be a problem as it is a simple 2D game with few buttons and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to run Unity3D engine on the raspberry using raspian, as the linux builds only support x86/x64 architecture, and do not support ARM.

You can in theory install Android on your raspberry and run it that way (its not an emulation, you need an actual android install) but its convoluted quite 'hacky'

Comment: how about running on Windows 10 IoT? Can I build standalone for windows and run it on raspberry that's using Windows 10 IoT?

Comment: if you build targeting UniversalWindowsPlatform it might work. I haven't got much expereience with that. it will not work using standard windows .exe for sure (targeting x86/x64)

Answer (score 1):

You can run it using a WebGL build: [Run Unity game on Raspberry Pi 4 with Picade arcade machine](https://kebetsi.medium.com/run-unity-game-on-raspberry-pi-4-with-picade-arcade-machine-c54210d64b7a).